# Django .."join" query?

Tags: python, django

guys, how or where is the "join" query in Django?

i think that Django dont have "join"..but how ill make  join?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using models, the select_related method will return the object for any foreign keys you have set up (up to a limit you specify) within that model.

Comment: This only helps with out-going foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [model relationships](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#relationships) and [accessing related objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#ref-models-relations).

Comment: i did it, thanks, but the true is that im reading and reading and think that django doc's need more examples.

Answer (score -10):

SQL Join queries are a hack because SQL doesn't have objects or navigation among objects.

Objects don't need "joins".  Just access the related objects.