# How to implement join in django with postgres?

Tags: django, django-select-related

Basically , I have three tables BusinessCards ,BusinessCardsIdentifiers and Identifiers.Primary key of BusinessCards and Identifiers are stored into BusinessCardsIdentifiers . I want to find a way to write single query and find related data from all related tables.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django .."join" query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210711/django-join-query)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save queries you need to prefetch the data with [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) when you are using many-to-many relationship, or [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for one-to-one or foreing key relationhip. You can specify which ones to prefetch or let Django decide.